# WPF: ICollectionView.Refresh() refreshing only when UIElement loses focus, instead of Text and Value Change

Tags: wpf, refresh, uielement, icollectionview

I have an `ICollectionView`, called `RepozitorijumWrapper` which should display my entities based on six fields. The fields are two `TextBox` and four `DateTimePicker` elements. Basically, every time any of those elements change (even by a number/letter) I want the list to  update.

My `DateTimePicker` and `TextBox` elements are bound to DateTime and string properties, that have the `RepozitorijumWrapper.Refresh()` code in their setter. When I tested my application, the filter did work, but only once you left the field. After that I tried calling the `Refresh()` method from the controller, or rather using the `TextChanged` event for the `TextBox` elements, and the `ValueChanged` for the `DateTimePicker`s. This changed nothing. The filter does work, but it isn't refreshed the way I'd like it to refresh.

Since my code is pretty much six copies of the same thing, with changed names and types, I'll only paste one instance of each relevant part of code.

Here's the property:

```
public string SifraTima
{
    get {return sifraTima;}
    set
    {
        if(!sifraTima.Equals(value))
        {
            sifraTima = value;
            RepozitorijumWrapper.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the XAML for that property:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSifraTima" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="3,3,30,3" Text="{Binding Path=SifraTima}" TextChanged="txtSifraTima_TextChanged" />
```

Here's the event handler:

```
private void txtSifraTima_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    presenter.RepozitorijumWrapper.Refresh();
}
```

Here's my ICollectionView, created in the constructor of my presenter class:

```
RepozitorijumWrapper = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(rezervacije.Kolekcija);

RepozitorijumWrapper.Filter = itm =>
    ((Rezervacija)itm).SifraTerena.Contains(SifraTerena) &&
    ((Rezervacija)itm).SifraTima.Contains(SifraTima) &&
    ((Rezervacija)itm).VremeZauzimanja <= VremeZauzimanjaDo &&
    ((Rezervacija)itm).VremeZauzimanja >= VremeZauzimanjaOd &&
    ((Rezervacija)itm).VremeOslobadjanja <= VremeOslobadjanjaDo &&
    ((Rezervacija)itm).VremeOslobadjanja >= VremeOslobadjanjaOd;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding on the `Text` property of the `TextBox` is set to only update the property after the focus is lost by default. To change that behavior, you can specify a value for `UpdateSourceTrigger` like so:

```
Text="{Binding Path=SifraTima, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) has more information on UpdateSourceTrigger